# 'JsonSerializable' not found issue in ZendFramework 2 application

Tags: php, json, serialization, zend-framework2

I have a Doctrine entity in my Zend 2 Project as follows.

```
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JsonSerializable;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @author SWISS BUREAU
 *
 */
class ProductVersion implements JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var $id
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    // continue...
    // JsonSerializable implementation available below..
```

My php version is

```
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul 12 2013 20:21:47)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

and I am getting the following error while the application executes.

```
Fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in /var/www/xx.....
```

what can be the possible reason and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[`JsonSerializable` @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)

**(PHP 5 >= 5.4.0)**

Your PHP Version is too low. Has nothing to do with ZF2 ;)

Comment: is there any Zend class/interface where I can get the similar functionality?

Comment: Nothing that would be called automatically when you do `serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

Interface JsonSerializable has started supported in PHP 5.4 or later version.
You need to upgrade your PHP version to use It.